# Importing CRM data with Measurement Protocol: Is it possible to batch send for multiple UserIds?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm trying to send data from my CRM to GA via measurement protocol, however I don't understand how to send all my custom dimensions for ALL uids at the same time. Would I have to make hundreds of POST requests?

Also, we are not currently tracking the users of this website on GA, so there is no user ids to make a match, we merely want to have this data available for remarketing in Google Ads. 
In this case, would Data Import be the best since we can upload our own IDs via a custom dimension?

Ex
    POST /batch HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.google-analytics.com

```
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=554&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=556&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome
```

Answer (score 0):

The batching method allows for a max of 20 requests per batch. Each request in the batch is a single hit. Doing something like the following would record Custom dimension 1 for userid 1 2 and 3.

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome&uid=1&cd1=Customdimension1
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fabout&uid=2&cd1=Customdimension1
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fcontact&uid=3&cd1=Customdimension1
```

By using uid it helps Google analytics preform internal processing by the user.  If you put the user id as a custom dimension this will not happen as Google analytics doesn't understand that this will be your user id.

> User Id
>
> This field is required if Client ID (cid) is not specified in the request. This is intended to be a known identifier for a user provided by the site owner/tracking library user. It must not itself be PII (personally identifiable information). The value should never be persisted in GA cookies or other Analytics provided storage.